# Does `dse spark` default to use `local_dc`? How do I change it?

Tags: datastax-enterprise

For DSE 4.6, does `dse spark` default to limitting to `Analytics` datacenter (`spark.cassandra.connection.local_dc`)? Does the same apply for `dse shark`?

Last, but not least, can I change which datacenter they default to somewhere? I have migrated from the `SimpleDseSnitch` to `GossipingPropertyFileSnitch` and would like to run Spark jobs on a non-`Analytics` datacenter.

Answer (score 2):

> For DSE 4.6, does dse spark default to limitting to Analytics
>   datacenter (spark.cassandra.connection.local_dc)? Does the same apply
>   for dse shark?

Yes, this is what the DSESimpleSnitch does. See the docs for details:
http://docs.datastax.com/en/datastax_enterprise/4.6/datastax_enterprise/deploy/deployConfigRep.html?scroll=configReplication__configRepDseSimpleSnitch

> Last, but not least, can I change which datacenter they default to somewhere?

Yes

> I have migrated from the SimpleDseSnitch to GossipingPropertyFileSnitch and 
>   would like to run Spark jobs on a non-Analytics datacenter.

When using the GossipingPropertyFileSnitch, you tell each node where it belongs in the cassandra-rackdc.properties file. See docs:
http://docs.datastax.com/en/datastax_enterprise/4.6/datastax_enterprise/deploy/deployConfigRep.html?scroll=configReplication__GossipingPropertyFile-snitch

Comment: Thanks, phact! Regarding "Last, but not least, can I change which datacenter they default to somewhere?" you didn't specify how I could set the default datacenter used by Spark. Will I need to set `spark.cassandra.connection.local_dc` manually every time I boot `dse shark`?

Comment: Yes, GossipingPropertyFileSnitch.

Comment: I'm confused on what your question is. You configure the datacenter in the cassandra-rackdc.properties file when you use GPFS. You do this for every DSE node, including those running spark.

Comment: Oh, I am sorry. My question regards to `dse shark`; How can I set which `local_dc` it uses on startup?

Comment: It should be the local DC if the machine you are pointing to. Do you have multiple analytics DCs?

Comment: No, but I would like to migrate to run spark on my `Cassandra` DC that has vnodes enabled.